# react-native-maps fill color to each region

Tags: ios, geojson, react-native-maps

I need to render dynamic GeoJSON data to a map in iOS.

I am using `react-native-maps`. I was able to render the geojson to the map, but it only shows the stroke of each region and not the fill color:

[image]

How can I add a unique color to each state or region on the map?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your GeoJSON has a valid fill value at `geojson.features[n].properties.fill`. If your GeoJSON doesn't already have that value, you can write a function to add it. For example:

```
const colorizedGeojson = {
    ...geojson,
    features: geojson.features.map(feature => ({
        ...feature,
        properties: {
            ...feature.properties,
            fill: getColor(feature.properties.values.population)
        }
    })),
};
```

You'll have to implement your own `getColor` function, depending on the data you want to represent. The `population` value used here is just an example. Using d3 interpolation to get the color for the value you want to represent is a common choice.

Once you've added the `fill` property to your GeoJSON data, you can pass that object to the component. Make sure you don't pass the `fillColor` property to the component, as that would override the feature colors.

```
<Geojson geojson={colorizedGeojson} />
```

That's it! The `react-native-maps` component will render each region/country with the color you choose:

[image: colorized map example]

Answer (score -1):

If it still relevant, you can use multiple `<Geojson /`> components inside `<MapView>` and set different `fillColor` prop to them depends on your condition.