# React-native-maps fill regions with different colors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, geojson, react-native-maps

I'm using the `react-native-maps` library to render GeoJSON data to a map. Is there a way to fill regions with different colors? I have a GeoJSON file of countries, and I'm passing it into the `<Geojson>` component.

```
<MapView
   style={styles.map}
   zoomEnabled
   provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
 >
      <Geojson 
         fillColor="red"
         geojson={geojson}
      />
</MapView>
```

This is the result:

[image: Filled map with red color]

Similar question: [react-native-maps fill color to each region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328598/react-native-maps-fill-color-to-each-region).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to use multiple `<Geojson />` component and set different `fillColor` prop to them. Something like that.

```
{geojson.features.map(feature => {
   const insertedObject = {
       features: [feature]
   };

   if (feature.id === 'AGO' ||feature.id === 'AFG' || feature.id === 'RUS') {
        return <Geojson 
                  geojson={insertedObject}
                  fillColor={'orange'}
               />
   }
    return <Geojson 
             geojson={insertedObject}
             fillColor={'red'}
           />
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to add `fill` property to the features in your GeoJSON object before passing it to the `<Geojson />` component.

```
const colorizedGeojson = {
    ...geojson,
    features: geojson.features.map(feature => ({
        ...feature,
        properties: {
            ...feature.properties,
            fill: getColor(feature.properties.values.population)
        }
    })),
};
```

You'll have to implement your own `getColor` function, depending on the data you want to represent. The `population` value used here is just an example. Using d3 interpolation to get the color for the value you want to represent is a common choice.

Once you've added the `fill` property to your GeoJSON data, you can pass that object to the component instead of the raw GeoJSON. Make sure you don't pass the `fillColor` property to the component, as that would override the feature colors.

```
<Geojson geojson={colorizedGeojson} />
```

Et voila! The `react-native-maps` component will render each region/country with the color you choose:

[image: colorized map example]